# Regexp instruction in SQL

Tags: sql, json, regexp-substr, alibaba-cloud, dataworks

After applying function `GET_JSON_OBJECT(features, '$.field')` I get the values:

```
{10:3,300:286}
{300:86}
{300:3,50:1}
```

How to get the value after 300 then?

Needed result is

```
286
86
3
```

Comment: Every DBMS has a completely different toolkit of regex functions. What DBMS are you using?

Comment: DataWorks (Alibaba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
GET_JSON_OBJECT(features, '$.field.300')
```

Or

```
 GET_JSON_OBJECT(features, '$.field."300"')
```